# Http Get Request With Id Attached to End in Angular 2.3.1

Tags: angular, http

I have tried to use the below code for a get request with a user_id, however it doesn't work.

```
getProjects(user_id){
this.loadToken();
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
let params = new URLSearchParams();    
params.set('user_id', user_id);
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/project/all/' , {headers: headers, search: params})
  .map(res => res.json());
```

}

When I place the full path in the get request without trying the params, it returns fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RequestOptions` as below:

```
getProjects(user_id){
  this.loadToken();

  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');

  let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  params.set('user_id', user_id);

  let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
  requestOptions.search = params;

  this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/project/all/', requestOptions)
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: what about the header component